# Jenkins pipeline: How to prompt "Do you really want to build?"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using Jenkins with Pipeline Jobs and of course the awesome Jenkinsfile.
Twice now a developer accidentally clicked on the build button, which ended up causing a bit of chaos. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to have something like a popup that asks "Do you really want to start this build?".

Any ideas on this user related issue are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the article [*Controlling the Flow with Stage, Lock, and Milestone*](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/) in the Jenkins blog, which covers a bit more than only asking for confirmation.

Essentially, there is the [`input`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#input-wait-for-interactive-input) step, which requires user input to continue pipeline execution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `input` step as suggested by StephenKing is that you won't be able to run the build automatically anymore as it will always ask for the user to confirm the input step manually. This prevents "automatic builds" triggered e.g. by webhooks or CRON jobs.

One workaround is to have a timeout and the build is triggered if the timeout is over. Like that, a user can at least abort an unintended build. But this leads to significantly longer build times.

What we did in my old company was, that we created a so called "parametrized" build, which had a simple checkbox "Do you really want to build this job" that resulted in a flag `REALLY_BUILD` as an environment variable. You can then ask for `${REALLY_BUILD}==1` in the Jenkinsfile. Every time a developer triggers a build, he has to check the box, otherwise the build will not start / immediately stop.

When you trigger your job via a webhook, you can pass a parameter `REALLY_BUILD` as an URL parameter (see [this comment in the Jenkins tracker](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27902?focusedCommentId=235397&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-235397)) and access it in the Jenkinsfile as before.

Here is another resource for [how to use parameters in Pipelines](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230611087-Pipeline-Create-a-Parameterized-Pipeline-using-Template).

Comment: If you want to prevent automatic deploys to a given environment, production for example, then you aren't making a good case...